# Stopping draught between bottom of plasterboard and floor UK

Tags: drywall, insulation

I'm trying to stop a cold spot coming from under my kitchen units.

When removing the kickboards, we can see that there is the usual gap between the base of plasterboard/drywall and concrete floor (the flooring does not continue under the units).

Access to this space is impeded somewhat by the kitchen unit legs.

Can the gap between floor and wall be covered? If so, what is the best material to use for insulation?

Comment: One does not seal a home at the interior wall finish. What's going on _outside_ the wall? Also, insulation is not a draft stop. It's an insulator. You need an air barrier. Or both.

Comment: @Matthew S. You might add a picture showing what you mean (but I can see the challenge taking one in such a confined space).

Answer (score 1):

I have/had a similar problem. Loft insulation helped for a while but didn't stop the draught completely.

I managed to contrive a long enough extension tube for my expanding foam gun to reach the wall behind the cabinets and was able to fill the gaps. I was lucky that although the flooring doesn't continue under the cabinets, the floor insulation (thin layer of foil backed foam) did and was preventing some of the wind blowing up through the floor boards. It was still a messy job and I have yet to see how effective it is.

For those unfamiliar with UK house construction, I expect OP has double skinned brick and block walls, suspended floors over a small void, and air bricks that allow that space to remain ventilated. The problem is that the floorboards are not air tight against each other or against the walls and are often made worse by being cut up by plumbers and electricians. It's not particularly common to see a useful crawl space, timber frame, cladding, house wrap, etc.

As far as I can tell this problem can only be dealt with properly before the kitchen or even the flooring is installed by running the flooring underlay or similar up the walls and sealing it there, e.g. by clamping it behind the skirting, or filling everything in sight with expanding foam. Unsure why this isn't done more carefully as a matter of course...

Answer (score 0):

Caulking or caulking with backer board/rod if gap is big.

If bigger than a gap, then fill before caulking.  Fill would be a similar panel to the wall with sealing on the back/wall side.

In the future if major work done on the walls, extra insulation and poly vapour barrier should stop cold drafts coming in.